# Override non virtual bound method in viewmodel (AvaloniaUI)

Tags: data-binding, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I have a core project with a login view and viewmodel, the assembly is published as nuget.
Now in my custom project I want to change some behavior like for example the login.
So I created a `CustomLoginView` that contains the original `LoginView` and a `CustomViewModel : LoginViewModel` with a new `Login()` which hides the original one.

**The problem is now there is still the original `Login()` called.**

- Is this because the binding in the core project was created on compiling and it goes on `LoginViewModel.Login()` explicitly?
- If this is correct is it possible to for example to trigger reevaluate the bindings on current data context?

A workaround should be be to make the method virtual in the `LoginViewModel`.
Since I would like to have the core project customizable this would mean I have to make everything virtual. I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because hiding does not change the method in LoginView.

Consider the following:

```cs
class LoginView
{
  public void Login()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("This was called from LoginView");
  }
}

class CustomLoginView : LoginView
{
  public new void Login()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("This was called from CustomLoginView");
  }
}
```

If I were to create a CustomLoginView like so...

```cs
CustomLoginView view = new CustomLoginView();
view.Login();
```

The expected output would be `This was called from CustomLoginView`.

However if I did the following...

```cs
LoginView view = new CustomLoginView();
view.Login();
```

The output would instead be `This was called from LoginView`.

If you don't override a virtual then the method will not be replaced when called from the base class.  The same is true if you cast to the base.

```cs
CustomLoginView view = new CustomLoginView();
((LoginView)view).Login();
```

The expected output would also be `This was called from LoginView`.
Overriding a virtual is the only way to change this behavior.  When you override a virtual, the behavior of the overriding method will persist in all of these cases.

Comment: I just wonder because I do not have compiled Bindings enabled. So there should be on runtime a lookup for a method called Login in the DataContext which is object?. So why is the 'original' Login selected? Maybe both are found and the first one is picked?

Comment: It has nothing to do with compiled bindings, it's just how C# works.